# How to remove right left padding of `Form` in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-form

How to remove the left and right Padding of a Form in SwiftUI? Every View I create has padding in the leading and trailing.

[image]

Here is my code

```
init() {
            UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section{
                    Picker(selection: $selectedCurrency, label: Text("Date Format"), content: {
                        ForEach(0 ..< self.dateStyles.count) { (index:Int) in
                            Text("\(self.dateStyles[index])")
                           
                        }
                    })
                }
            }.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"), displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear(){
                if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] != "1"{
                //some code
                }
        }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a Form design out-of-the-box. Don't like Form, use List.

Answer (score 3):

Using something else is probably best but this removes the padding.

```
Form {
 ...               
}.padding(.leading, -16)
.padding(.trailing, -16)
```

Comment: I agree that this isn't an optimal solution, but along with .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()), it works when you have to use Form.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `List` instead of a `Form`, take a look at the different [list styles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle), I think you are after `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())`